# How to load multiple images in Kivy without running out of memory

Tags: python, image, kivy

I've had this issue for a while now but can't seem to find the solution for it. Basically I have around 90+ images that I want to load in my Kivy app. It works fine on Windows and Linux, but when I try to run it on my Android phone it gives me the following error after playing around in the app for a bit: `Exception: Unable to allocate memory for texture (size is 108360)`.

I've tried putting my images in Google Firebase storage and loading them with AsyncImage instead. But that caused me even more issues.

Is there a more efficient way to load multiple images in Kivy? If so I would like to know how since this method is not working for me. Thanks!

Comment: I think you probably ultimately want to either load only a subset of the images at any time, or (if you need to display them all) generate smaller versions, or perhaps a mixture of both.

Comment: Do you need to display all the 90+ images at the same time?

Comment: They are not all in the same screen. I have 5 screens that contain the images.

Comment: Perhaps an `on_enter()` method for each `Screen` to load the images for that `Screen`. And an `on_leave()` to destroy those `Images`. Might need to call `remove_from_cache()` for each of those images.

Comment: Good idea. I'll try to do it that way. Thanks!